# afterClosed() executing early for dialogRef

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, dialog

In Test.component.ts I have an on click function in which I have dialog.open() and dialog.afterClosed()
In test-dialog.component.ts, I do some basic code after that I have dialogRef.close()

The issue here for me is after when dialog.open() has started executing, dialog.afterClosed() begins execution.
Later in dialog component when .close() is called I am not able to get any of the functionality of functions that I had called inside afterClosed().

Comment: can you please add the base component and dialog component code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see that is:

```
//you get a reference of the dialog "dialogRef"
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(...))

//you listen the reference to close "dialogRef"
dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(..)
```

You "dialog" has a button

```
//you pass the value of "object" -the property of [mat-dialog-close]-
//can be a simple variable or a object or array
<button mat-button 
    [mat-dialog-close]="object" >Ok</button>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.
I was sending [mat-dialog-close]="true". I removed this from html. At the end of the function called on click of button I added this.dalogRef.close('_custom_message_').
Now, it's working the way I want it to.
Upon checking the flow I am able to understand that after dialog.open() the code loaded till dialogRef.afterClosed(), it didnot subscribe to it untill it got response from pop-up component, this.dialogRef('_custom_message_').
Thank You for your response @Eliseo

Comment: To be more precise, "not execute the function inside subscribe until you close the dialog -do `this.dialogRef('custom_message')` ", but the subscription is done. To close the mat-dialog you can use `this.dialogRef.close(..here can put arguments or not..)`. or add the directive `[mat-dialog-close]="'custom message'"` to one button